# [TF] Extrapolation into future - Wierd Chain?

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everyone,

I have the issue, that while running moveIt, I get transforms errors:

```
[ERROR] [1410959502.463512661]: Transform error: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1410959502.460805976 but the latest data is at time 1410959502.410336017, when looking up transform from frame [finger_1_link_0] to frame [camera_top/camera_top_depth_optical_frame]
```

Now, following [this](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Debugging%20tf%20problems) guide, I debugged the transforms, I appended the results below. What I was wondering is: Why is the chain so long and looped? Might this be the root of the issue?

```
RESULTS: for camera_top/camera_top_depth_optical_frame to finger_1_link_0
Chain is: segment_0 -> camera_top/camera_top_link -> camera_top/camera_top_rgb_frame -> camera_top/camera_top_link -> camera_front/camera_front_link -> segment_0 -> camera_top/camera_top_depth_frame -> camera_front/camera_front_link -> palm -> segment_7 -> camera_front/camera_front_depth_frame -> camera_front/camera_front_rgb_frame -> finger_1_link_1 -> finger_1_link_0 -> finger_1_link_2 -> finger_2_link_1 -> finger_2_link_0 -> finger_2_link_2 -> finger_middle_link_1 -> finger_middle_link_0 -> finger_middle_link_2 -> palm -> palm -> palm -> segment_6 -> segment_0 -> segment_1 -> segment_2 -> segment_3 -> segment_4 -> segment_5
Net delay     avg = 0.055249: max = 0.117458

Frames:
Frame: camera_front/camera_front_depth_frame published by /camera_front_base_link Average Delay: -0.00940285 Max Delay: 0
Frame: camera_front/camera_front_link published by /second_kinect_broadcaster Average Delay: -0.0993219 Max Delay: 0
Frame: camera_front/camera_front_link published by /second_kinect_broadcaster Average Delay: -0.0993219 Max Delay: 0
Frame: camera_front/camera_front_rgb_frame published by /camera_front_base_link_1 Average Delay: -0.00940964 Max Delay: 0
Frame: camera_top/camera_top_depth_frame published by /camera_top_base_link Average Delay: -0.00945783 Max Delay: 0
Frame: camera_top/camera_top_link published by /camera_top_link_broadcaster Average Delay: -0.00942012 Max Delay: 0
Frame: camera_top/camera_top_link published by /camera_top_link_broadcaster Average Delay: -0.00942012 Max Delay: 0
Frame: camera_top/camera_top_rgb_frame published by /camera_top_base_link_1 Average Delay: -0.00942155 Max Delay: 0
Frame: finger_1_link_0 published by /robot_tf_state_publisher Average Delay: -0.496956 Max Delay: 0
Frame: finger_1_link_1 published by /robot_tf_state_publisher Average Delay: 0.00512914 Max Delay: 0.0639241
Frame: finger_1_link_2 published by /robot_tf_state_publisher Average Delay: -0.496976 Max Delay: 0
Frame: finger_2_link_0 published by /robot_tf_state_publisher Average Delay: -0.496954 Max Delay: 0
Frame: finger_2_link_1 published by /robot_tf_state_publisher Average Delay: 0.00513452 Max Delay: 0.0639276
Frame: finger_2_link_2 published by /robot_tf_state_publisher Average Delay: -0.496969 Max Delay: 0
Frame: finger_middle_link_0 published by /robot_tf_state_publisher Average Delay: -0.496951 Max Delay: 0
Frame: finger_middle_link_1 published by /robot_tf_state_publisher Average Delay: 0.00513811 Max Delay: 0.0639306
Frame: finger_middle_link_2 published by /robot_tf_state_publisher Average Delay: -0.496963 Max Delay: 0
Frame: palm published by /robot_tf_state_publisher Average Delay: -0.496948 Max Delay: 0
Frame: palm published by /robot_tf_state_publisher Average Delay: -0.496948 Max Delay: 0
Frame: palm published by /robot_tf_state_publisher Average Delay: -0.496948 Max Delay: 0
Frame: palm published by /robot_tf_state_publisher Average Delay: -0.496948 Max Delay: 0
Frame: segment_1 published by /robot_tf_state_publisher Average Delay: 0.00514182 Max Delay: 0.0639336
Frame: segment_2 published by /robot_tf_state_publisher Average Delay: 0.00514508 Max Delay: 0.0639368
Frame: segment_3 published by /robot_tf_state_publisher Average Delay: 0.00514861 Max Delay: 0.0639399
Frame: segment_4 published by /robot_tf_state_publisher Average Delay: 0.00515163 Max Delay: 0.063943
Frame: segment_5 published by /robot_tf_state_publisher Average Delay: 0.00515438 Max Delay: 0.0639463
Frame: segment_6 published by /robot_tf_state_publisher Average Delay: 0.00515731 Max Delay: 0.0639497
Frame: segment_7 published by /robot_tf_state_publisher Average Delay: 0.00515987 Max Delay: 0.0639524

All Broadcasters:
Node: /camera_front_base_link 99.3663 Hz, Average Delay: -0.00940285 Max Delay: 0
Node: /camera_front_base_link_1 99.4127 Hz, Average Delay: -0.00940964 Max Delay: 0
Node: /camera_front_base_link_2 99.3969 Hz, Average Delay: -0.00941993 Max Delay: 0
Node: /camera_front_base_link_3 99.4064 Hz, Average Delay: -0.00940085 Max Delay: 0
Node: /camera_top_base_link 99.4075 Hz, Average Delay: -0.00945783 Max Delay: 0
Node: /camera_top_base_link_1 99.4135 Hz, Average Delay: -0.00942155 Max Delay: 0
Node: /camera_top_base_link_2 99.4092 Hz, Average Delay: -0.00940796 Max Delay: 0
Node: /camera_top_base_link_3 99.4122 Hz, Average Delay: -0.00936636 Max Delay: 0
Node: /camera_top_link_broadcaster 99.404 Hz, Average Delay: -0.00942012 Max Delay: 0
Node: /pinch_frame_broadcaster 99.4173 Hz, Average Delay: -0.00934003 Max Delay: 0
Node: /robot_tf_state_publisher 110.242 Hz, Average Delay: -0.451271 Max Delay: 0.012499
Node: /second_kinect_broadcaster 9.94165 Hz, Average Delay: -0.0993219 Max Delay: 0
```

Here is my transform tree:
[image: image description]
[image: image description]

I'm thankful for any hints,

Rabe

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192871/%5Btf%5D-extrapolation-into-future---wierd-chain?/) by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 683 on 2014-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have many sources for your transforms, and you need to make sure that the transform data has arrived.

Duplicate: http://answers.ros.org/question/39968/extrapolationexception-very-small-time-difference/ @Lorenz 's answer is valid

> Just use
> [waitForTransform](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1Transformer.html#a6d5a0ef43029723a4537102d5254b431)
> or
> [tf::MessageFilter](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1MessageFilter.html).
> Also, make sure you went through [this
> tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/tf%20and%20Time%20%28C%2B%2B%29).

The displayed chain has a bug in it: https://github.com/ros/geometry_experimental/issues/22 is why the listing is wrong at the top.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) on 2014-09-18**:
Pardon, just that I understand it correctly:
-The command line output is not an issue

- I or actually some node in moveIt should use the waitForTransform method
- Reducing the publishers might help in my case.

**Comment by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) on 2014-09-18**:
Ok, I joined all the camera-related publishers into 1 publisher. The issue still persisted. Since I don't want to dive into the moveIt code, to implement MessageFilters, I am dating the transforms from the cameras into the past. This should not be an issue, since they are static. Thanks!